# Can you create a function that can use the result of a parameter to specify the value to change?

Tags: java, methods

EDIT: Some people (probably a lot of people) didn't get what I was asking. I'll paste the full code and try and explain it better.

```
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Shape;
import javafx.scene.Group;

import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public abstract class Part {
    double x;
    double y;
    double width;
    double height;
    double angle;

    public Part(double x, double y, double width, double height, double angle) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.angle = angle;
        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().addAll();
    }

    abstract void createPart(Shape shape);
    abstract void addPart(Group group);
    public void setPartProperties(Parameter... properties) {
        //This can set any variable of any type to any value based on some parameters I don't understand. FOR EXAMPLE setPartProperties({x, 100}, {y, 50})
        //I don't know what the notation would look like so don't get caught up in the whole {variable, value} format as an input, I just made that up.
        //This is the part I need help with. BTW the parameter class was an arbitrary choice for the variable type,
        // IK it won't work since I want to be able to change any variable of any type to any value.
    }

}
```

*Read the comment in the setPartProperties() method.
Okay so lemme break down this code. It is the main class that a ton of subclasses will extend from. Let's say a create a class Wheel that extends Part. It would look like this

```
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Shape;
import javafx.scene.Group;

import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class Wheel extends Part {

    public Part(double x, double y, double width, double height, double angle) {
        super(x, y, width, height, angle);
        setPartProperties({x, 100}, {y, 100}, {width, 50}, {height, 40}, {angle, 0})

    }

    @Override
    public void createPart(Shape shape) {
        //Make some JavaFX circle object, IDK it doesn't matter
    }
    @Override
    public void addPart(Group group) {
        //Add that object to a JavaFX group; also doesn't matter
    }

}
```

Okay, so this code is just an extension of the Part class and, ignoring everything else, uses its setPartProperties() method. I have to stress that the **format of the inputs to the method's parameters don't matter** and I just made them up on the spot. The final result doesn't have to be {variable, value} to add a parameter to the method. I just want to be able to specify a value and which variable to apply it to. As the parameters of a method (which does just that).

EDIT: While I don't know what the final syntax for the input of the method will be, I do want it to be a Pair system. For example if I used this method its parameters would look something like this.

```
setPartProperties((x, 100), (y, 100));

public void setPartProperties() {
    //Stuff
}
```

I want to make the one method do it all so you can just add whatever things you want to it at any time. Back to my simulator, let's say I wanted to change the angle of a part later on. I could just write setPartProperties((angle, -30)); I don't want to have to make a new HashMap every time. Instead, I want a for loop to generate a local HashMap inside the method and then get its values and apply those to their corresponding variables. The only type of method that I know does this is

```
public void thing(double... input) {
    for (double i: input) {
        //do somestuff
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is that it does stuff to each double. I would want to have two values per each new i. I need to replace double... with somethingElse... that has two inputs.

Comment: *I want a method that the parameters are what the value is equal to and what that value needs to be applied to.* I don't follow that. Please explain **how** you want to use this; give an example, because I do not understand your question. *if I somehow set a value of 10 and type x* Again, what does that mean in this context?

Comment: @Sweeper I just looked it up, and I can look into it, but I'm a serious noob so could you just explain what it is so I can see if I wanna spend hours figuring it out. It's not really you, I appreciate the advice but that looks too complex for me(never heard of anything close to that hard). And maybe that just the nature of what I'm asking for, IDK.

Comment: Now that I saw your code, I changed my mind. If you are always going to be calling `setPartProperties` with a bunch of hardcoded values like this, then I recommend saving those hardcoded values into a JSON file on disk, and reading and parsing that file instead. If you are just too lazy to write a ton of getters/setters, you can try something like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org).

Comment: @Sweeper I'm sorry **_what??_** I have no clue about anything you're talking about. Maybe this will explain how much of a beginner I am. **What is a JSON file???**  **Parsing???** I really do appreciate you helping but I just can't speak about code on that level. In order to explain it to me, think about explaining it to someone that's only coded on code.org! I have more knowledge than that, but IG I'm just too much of a novice to understand. EDIT: Ah... this is coded in Java so that might be why I didn't know what a JSON file was but still, though. I'm lost.

Comment: [Builder pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-pattern-in-java/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch are you saying to make something like Part.setVar(X).setValue(100) or something like that? That could totally solve the problem if I understand whatever builder patterns mean. Well not fully. I would still need the setVar() method to use the input to set which variable it affects so it only delays the problem. Still tho it solves the whole need two things in one parameter

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's a great idea! Although judging from the first revision, OP doesn't seem to want a setter for every field, this can be solved with Lombok. OP, first learn about the builder pattern, then read about how to install and use Lombok to generate a builder pattern with the link in my comment.

Comment: Okay so this seems promising I think, but now I am done for the day. Tomorrow I will read up on both of your links. Builder pattern and Lombok.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Why don't you just write setters for all of your variables and use them?  One very simple way to handle this is just to get rid of all variables in your classes, and define a `Map<String,Object> vars = new HashMap<>` in your abstract base class, then to set any variable you just do `vars.put(name, value)`.  That is feasible, but do you want to do that?  And, if so or not, why or why not?  You can edit your question to add info, rather than in comments if you wish.

Comment: Don't import `com.sun` classes in your code, they are not designed to be public API and can change without notice, so using them could make your code incompatible with future Java versions.

Comment: @Jewelsea sorry about that I meant to import javafx.scene.shape. Thanks for letting me know about this! I just used the auto-import and clicked the first one so yeah. Also, I'm choosing to edit in comments because I already have edited the post a lot and I think it is easy to understand know as it's gonna get. The reason I never thought of that (which I still don't know how to apply it to my thing) is that I had no clue what that was! I've coded Java for a year in a half on a school robotics team and we just used an enormous SDK. I didn't start coding raw Java untill like three weeks ago.

Comment: To understand hash maps, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap but in general I'd recommend just using setter methods on your classes, but if that doesn't work for you, then hash map should work.

Comment: Okay, so I updated my post. I like the idea of using HashMaps and reflection but I want to do it all at once. Instead of creating a hashmap and then using the method to get its values, I want to use the method to create a hashmap out of its inputs and then get the values from the hashmap. The problem is I need two values per one input and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Also this has been a long discussion and I even just got a message to not do that so to some up the final thing I need. Some class or method to convert two inputs to one object and use that in a method. Kind of a coordinate? (a, b) that kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection to achieve what you want as Sweeper had mentioned in their comment. If you want to use only static values for each new subclass, you can use set them manually hard coding when creating them. But if you want to set those fields dynamically (getting them from somewhere) then you can use reflection. One example code for your curiosity is:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestReflection {
    double x;
    double y;
    double width;
    double height;
    double angle;
    public TestReflection() {
    }
    public void setPartProperties(Map<String, Double> fieldValueMap) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<TestReflection> clazz = TestReflection.class;
        for(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : fieldValueMap.entrySet()) {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
            field.set(this, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Double> fieldAndValues = new HashMap<>();
        fieldAndValues.put("x", 10.0);
        fieldAndValues.put("y", 20.0);
        fieldAndValues.put("width", 30.0);
        fieldAndValues.put("height", 40.0);
        fieldAndValues.put("angle", 50.0);
        TestReflection testReflection = new TestReflection();
        testReflection.setPartProperties(fieldAndValues);
        System.out.println(testReflection);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestReflection{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                ", width=" + width +
                ", height=" + height +
                ", angle=" + angle +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I assume you want something like the setPartProperties method in my example, where it takes a map of field name and the value and it should set the values on the corresponding field. The rest of the code and the main method is for example only. You can write something according to your need. If you run this class, you will get output as:

```
TestReflection{x=10.0, y=20.0, width=30.0, height=40.0, angle=50.0}
```

Where each field was set through reflection based on the name. Even if this doesn't solve your problem, I HTH.

Comment: Thank you and this almost completely solves my problem. I want to merge the creation of the HashMap field and values and the for loop that gets and uses those values all into one method. I want to have the inputs of the method be used to create that HashMap. This would be fine except I need a way of storing two values in one input. Kind of like a coordinate but in this case ("some string", someValue) This is probably not that hard and there is probably a class for it so if there is then my comment is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using Reflection, HashMaps, and my own class called Pair. I created the Pair class to hold two values in one object. It just holds the objects **k** and **v**. It is a simpler version of the JavaFX Pair class.

```
public class Pair {
    Object k;
    Object v;

    public Pair(Object k, Object v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public Object getK() {
        return k;
    }
    public Object getV() {
        return v;
    }
}
```

My main Part Class has the setPartProperties() method which allows for multiple inputs, but to simply answer the question you only need a setPartProperty() method.

```
public void setPartProperty(Pair pair) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<Part> partClass = Part.class;
    Field field = partClass.getDeclaredField((String) pair.getK());
    field.set(this, pair.getV());
}
```

This simply uses Reflection to take the key from the Part object and use that as the "declared field" (variable to edit) and then takes the value from the Part object and sets that fields value to it with the set() method.

We can get more generalized, however. By creating an array out of input values using a method I don't actually know the name of, we can use a for each loop to apply every input value in the array to a HashMap.

```
public void setPartProperties(Pair... pairs) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Double> fieldAndValues = new HashMap<>();
    for (Pair pair: pairs) {
        fieldAndValues.put((String) pair.getK(), (Double) pair.getV());
    }
    Class<Part> partClass = Part.class;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : fieldAndValues.entrySet()) {
        Field field = partClass.getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
        field.set(this, entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

And now we can use that method in the Part class.

```
import javafx.scene.Group;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class Part {
    double x;
    double y;
    double width;
    double height;
    double angle;

    public Part(double x, double y, double width, double height, double angle) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    protected Part() {
    }

    abstract void createPart() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException;
    abstract void addPart(Group group);

    public void setPartProperties(Pair... pairs) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Double> fieldAndValues = new HashMap<>();
        for (Pair pair: pairs) {
            fieldAndValues.put((String) pair.getK(), (Double) pair.getV());
        }
        Class<Part> partClass = Part.class;
        for(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : fieldAndValues.entrySet()) {
            Field field = partClass.getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
            field.set(this, entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void setPartProperty(Pair pair) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<Part> partClass = Part.class;
        Field field = partClass.getDeclaredField((String) pair.getK());
        field.set(this, pair.getV());
    }
}
```

And now we can create a generic part using the part class and then use that class in the main class. Long story short we end up with a class that looks like this.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1920;
    final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080;

    Group mainGroup = new Group();
    Scene mainScene = new Scene(mainGroup, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(mainScene);
        stage.show();
        TestPart testPart = new TestPart();
        testPart.setPartProperties(new Pair("x", 100.), new Pair("y", 100.), new Pair("width", 100.), new Pair("height", 50.), new Pair("angle", 90.));
        testPart.setPartProperties();
        testPart.createPart();
        testPart.addPart(mainGroup);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```